# How to make Sign up page be root page in Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm running on Rails 4.0.0 with Devise 3.1.0. My routes are setup like this:

```
devise_for :users do
  root "devise/registrations#new"
end

resources :books
```

What I'm trying to do is make the Devise Sign Up Page be the Welcome Page for users if they haven't signed in but if their signed in they'll go to the Book Index. Right now it just gives me the standard Ruby on Rails:Welcome Aboard page as if Devise doesn't exist. How would I do this?

---

### Answer

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2393

```
devise_for :users
devise_scope :user do
  authenticated :user do
    root :to => 'books#index', as: :authenticated_root
  end
  unauthenticated :user do
    root :to => 'devise/registrations#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
  end
end
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
devise_for :users
devise_scope :user do
  authenticated :user do
    root to: 'books#index'
  end
  unauthenticated :user do
    root to: 'devise/registrations#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the root route out of the devise_for block and format it appropriately (as shown in the routes file).
2. Create a before_filter in your registrations_controller (may need to ovverride the default one devise provides) that checkes if current_user exists and redirects to the books path if it does.

Comment: If I do the first thing you say to do. I will get the error: `Could not find devise mapping for path "/".`

Comment: what route do you need to map to that registrations_controller? `/users/` or `/` ?