# Devise mapping to "/" with subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, routes

I have two devise models in my routes.rb:

```
devise_for :practitioners, controllers: { sessions: "practitioners/sessions" }
devise_for :dashboard_accounts
```

I would like that `doctor.mydomain.com/` maps to the **login page** of my practitioners.

I tried the following (the three commented blocks):

```
  constraints(:subdomain => 'doctor') do 
   # FIRST BLOCK 
   # devise_scope :practitioners do
      # root :to => 'practitioners/sessions#new'
   # end
   # SECOND BLOCK
   # scope module: 'practitioners' do
      # get '/' => 'practitioners/sessions#new'
   # end
   # THIRD BLOCK 
   # devise_scope :practitioners do
     # get "/", to: "devise/sessions#new"
   # end
  end
```

But nothings works. How should I do it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make Sign up page be root page in Devise?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18903145/how-to-make-sign-up-page-be-root-page-in-devise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

routes.rb :

```
 devise_for :practitioners, controllers: { sessions: "practitioners/sessions" }
  constraints(subdomain: /doctor*/) do
    devise_scope :practitioner do
      authenticated :practitioner do
        root :to => 'practitioners/practitioner#index', as: :practitioner_root
      end
      unauthenticated :practitioner do
        root :to => 'practitioners/sessions#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
      end
    end
  end
```